# asterisk: symbol lookup error res_pjsip_session.so undefined symbol pj_timer_entry_running

Tags: asterisk, voip, gateway

I have the Asterisk version 13.6 and Grandstream GXW 4104 (gateway fxo)
when the call to a gateway
asteroid crash
with this error

> Asterisk: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_pjsip_session.so: undefined symbol:
>   pj_timer_entry_running

what is the problem?